# Coalesce multiple levels based on type and "parent"

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets assume I have a database that looks something like this

```
id |Name | Type | budget | parentId | 
1 | a   |  1   | 5000   |  null    |
2 | b1  |  2   | 2200   | 1        |
3 | c2  |  2   | 2800   | 1        | 
4 | b_1 |  3   | 1000   | 2        |
5 | b_2 |  3   | 1200   | 2        |
6 | c_1 |  3   | 1600   | 3        |
7 | c_2 |  3   | 1200   | 3        |
```

And my desired Desired Output is this:

```
Name | Type | Budget | ParentName
a   |   1  | 5000   |   null
b1  |   2  | 2200   |   a
b_1 |   3  | 1000   |   b1
b_2 |   3  | 1200   |   b1
c1  |   2  | 2800   |   a
c_1 |   3  | 1600   |   c1
c_2 |   3  | 1200   |   c1
```

How would I go about doing that?

The requirements are essentially group by parent type, which is indicated by a type of 1 or a null parent id.  From there group first of type 2 below type 1, then all children of type 3 with type 2 as a parent below each type 2.

It's a bit of a nightmare and I tried using COALESCE but was a bit confused by the syntax when trying to get it to be

```
1 
  2
    3
    3
  2
    3
    3
    3
  2 ..
```

etc.

Any assistance here would be useful.

Note:  Type 1 will never have a parent, Type 2 will always have a parent of type 1, Type 3 will always have a parent of type 2.

Thanks,

Comment: How many levels of this hierarchy are there?

Comment: @forpas Only 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this sample data and only 3 levels you can do it with conditional sorting:

```
select t1.name, t1.type, t1.budget, t2.Name ParentName 
from tablename t1 left join tablename t2 
on t2.id = t1.parentid
order by 
  case when t2.parentid is null then t1.id else t1.parentid end,
  t1.id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pf8qpAHupxMey3N3e435XR/4).
Results:

```
| name | type | budget | parentname |
| ---- | ---- | ------ | ---------- |
| a    | 1    | 5000   |            |
| b1   | 2    | 2200   | a          |
| b_1  | 3    | 1000   | b1         |
| b_2  | 3    | 1200   | b1         |
| c1   | 2    | 2800   | a          |
| c_1  | 3    | 1600   | c1         |
| c_2  | 3    | 1200   | c1         |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can join the table to itself to get your desired output:

```
SELECT S1.Name, S1.Type, S1.Budget, S2.Name as ParentName FROM some_data S1 LEFT JOIN some_data S2 ON S1.parentId = S2.id;
```

Which produces the following output:

```
Name|Type|Budget|ParentName
a   |   1|  5000| null
b1  |   2|  2200|    a
c2  |   2|  2800|    a
b_1 |   3|  1000|   b1
b_2 |   3|  1200|   b1
c_1 |   3|  1600|   c2
c_2 |   3|  1200|   c2
```

Comment: kinda close, but I'm looking to fully expand each hierarchy so b_1 / b_2 nest under b1 rather than below, as I could use a group by to achieve the results above.

Comment: So is the issue that results aren't in the order you expect?

Comment: See the solution from @forpas.

Comment: If you need more than three levels, and this is a common querying pattern, consider using a graph database to store the data. If you'd like to stay within PostgreSQL, consider writing a PL/pgSQL function to generate values for each record, on which you can then sort. This can be applied at read time or as a trigger function at write time.